# How to search between 2 listboxes in PHP?

Tags: php, listbox

I want to search between 2 listboxes like `"from"` and `"to"`.

Comment: This is pretty unclear, could you elaborate a little, do you want to search a database?  What is a list box in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean get values from a database depending on the values of list boxes?  Then it would look like

```
mysql_query(
    'SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE from_field = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from_field']) .'"
    AND to_field = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to_field']) .'"',
$conn);
```

Providing the to and from select boxes are called `to_field` and `from_field` respectively, and you called your mysql connection $conn.

Comment: No i've store date in database and now i want to search e.g. in "from" field select 18 and "to" field select 21. it's mean i search between 18 to 21 if available than show me their records.